# Add an identifier to lines that are the same in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to add an identifier to sequential lines that are the same in a text file. For example, I have the following input file:

```
Apple
Apple
Apple
Banana
Banana
Pineapple
Pineapple
Pineapple
Pineapple
```

I want my output to be something like:

```
Apple_number_1
Apple_number_2
Apple_number_3
Banana_number_1
Banana_number_2
Pineapple_number_1
Pineapple_number_2
Pineapple_number_3
Pineapple_number_4
```

I have code that will print a line if the current and previous line are the same here:

```
my_file=open('/Users/Jo/Desktop/for_building.txt')
lines=my_file.readlines()

def lines_equal(curr_line, prev_line, compare_char):
   curr_line_parts = curr_line.split(' ')
   prev_line_parts = prev_line.split(' ')
   for item in zip(curr_line_parts, prev_line_parts):
       if item[0].startswith(compare_char):
           return item[0] == item[1]

results = []
prev_line = lines[0]

for line in lines[1:]:
    results.append(lines_equal(line, prev_line, 'Z'))
    prev_line = line
    print(prev_line)
```

How do I add the identifier at the end? I figure I will use a `while` loop. It gets tricky if the while loop gets caught in the `for` loop. Is there a clever way around this?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a default dict that would hold the count of each line, starting with zero (the default) and increment it each time the same line is encontered:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lineCounts = defaultdict(int)

for line in lines:
    lineCounts[line] = lineCounts[line] + 1
    print('{}_Number_{}'.format(line, lineCounts[line])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(lines)]

for group in groups:
    for index, fruit in enumerate(group, start=1):
        print(f"{fruit}_number_{index}")
```

Output:

```
Apple_number_1
Apple_number_2
Apple_number_3
Banana_number_1
Banana_number_2
Pineapple_number_1
Pineapple_number_2
Pineapple_number_3
Pineapple_number_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple iterative approach:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    cnt = 1   # initial counter value
    prev_line = None
    for line in f:
        if prev_line and line != prev_line: cnt = 1   # resetting counter
        print('{}_number_{}'.format(line.strip(), cnt))
        prev_line = line
        cnt += 1
```

The output:

```
Apple_number_1
Apple_number_2
Apple_number_3
Banana_number_1
Banana_number_2
Pineapple_number_1
Pineapple_number_2
Pineapple_number_3
Pineapple_number_4
```